# Deletion flags on Area51 questions can be cleared by deleting your own question and then undeleting it

Tags: bug, status-deferred, area-51

If you post a question, and one or two other users flag the question for deletion, you can clear the delete flags on the question by deleting the question yourself, and then undeleting it.

This pretty effectively prevents the question from being deleted by other users.

Answer (score 3):

If you witness behaviour like this, you should "Flag for moderator" at once.

It is a bug, but it is not a very common one, because (if I recall correctly) only the 10k users have the ability to *see* the deletion votes. (I may be wrong, please correct)

So, this means that it is only something that can be exploited by the already trusted users, and there are lots of way that they could abuse their powers. This is just one of them.

I think it's an interesting bug, but wouldn't necessarily be worth putting extra dev time into, because as noted, the 10k users already have other powers they could exploit if they intend to be malicious.

Comment: The problem is that you cannot flag it again.. so flagging for mod attention is going to be a little problematic! :-) I'd flag *another* post on the same question with a link to the actual problematic post in that case.

Answer (score -2):

Same with SO Questions....

Point?

Comment: Really?  Didn't know that.  It's a bug, all the same.