# Flagged as not-an-answer, all visible consequences except the answer actually going away happened - what gives?

Tags: support, flags, not-an-answer, undelete

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14501481/64976) as Not An Answer since the answerer changed it from an unhelpful answer to just a link. My flag was marked as helpful, my downvote reputation-loss was reverted, as was the answerers. The answer, for a *brief moment* went away. But is now back.

What happened?

Update: The reputation-change that was revoked when the question was deleted is now revoked. Again. However, I'm still curious about why my flag was marked as helpful but the obvious not-an-answer not deleted.

Comment: @gnat Thanks for the tags. Still very new at posting here. Dunno the 'lingo' yet. =D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The owner [deleted then undeleted](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/14501481/revisions) the post.

The deletion marked your flag as helpful automatically.

Since no edits were made, it deserves another flag. Unfortunately, you can only ever flag a post once for moderator attention like that, leaving a hole for someone to work around such flags if they suspected any were set (you cannot see them), see [Deletion flags on Area51 questions can be cleared by deleting your own question and then undeleting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52543/deletion-flags-on-area51-questions-can-be-cleared-by-deleting-your-own-question).

Comment: That makes sense. I *was* thinking that as I wrote my question. I should finish my thoughts, once in a while. =)

Comment: However, "You have already flagged this item for moderation attention". Despite my flag being in a "completed" state, so to speak. I find it a bit... limiting that I can only ever flag an item once. And never again. Maybe I should post this as a new question. Or trawl the vast archives to see if anyone else has...

Comment: No need. I deleted it.

Comment: @J.Steen: ah, yes, there is that limit. Interesting that you can work around a flag that way, although I doubt the OP was doing that on purpose.

Comment: As they couldn't possibly see the flag, I highly doubt it as well. =)

Comment: Ah, yep. There's already [this question right here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52543/deletion-flags-on-area51-questions-can-be-cleared-by-deleting-your-own-question) for instance.

Comment: @J.Steen: Ah thanks! I've incorporated that into my answer (if you don't mind. :-))

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'd never mind such an incorporation. ;)